# How can i include vendor from my another application in laravel

Tags: laravel

Need to reduce my project folder memory size. so that, changed the following line in bootstrap/autoload.php

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

changed to

require 'home/sites/laravel/myApp/vendor/autoload.php';

But all the Controller actions are called from main Application instead of sub application.

My Folder Structure,

.MyApp

```
   vendor
```

.MyApp1

```
 Include the vendor from myApp
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this (easily). And I'm not sure if that's a good idea even if you could. By >"Need to reduce my project folder memory size" you proably mean only "size" as in hard disk, not memory.

Comment: Just don't. Seriously. Even if you could make this work, every update would break your app.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do it.** It's a seriously bad practice and it also breaks everything you specify in your `composer.json` file, with a different state in production than expected. As the other guys told you before me, this would break your app at every dependency change.

I don't know how much big your app is. However, if you are deploying your app to a remote server, just try to get more space from your provider. If you're working locally, this is not a problem you should have anyway :)